# Ruby on Rails friendly_id, babosa гемы, проблема с транслитерацией

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Использую гемы friendly_id,babosa.

Модель models/product.rb:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
   has_many :tags

   def normalize_friendly_id(input)
    input.to_s.to_slug.normalize(transliterations: :russian).to_s
   end

end
```

Запускаю консоль, чтобы заполнить slug поле уже имеющихся строк:

```
Product.find_each(&:save)
```

Проверяю последний товар:

```
Product.last

#<Product id: 4972, name: "ВА 47-63, 2P 2А (C) EKF", created_at: "2016-01-27 11:32:39", updated_at: "2016-01-27 11:32:39", slug: 04b4aa2d-2bb9-46f9-8d49-cbb9d0c3f872">
```

Как можно увидеть, слаг сгенерировался без транслитерации, плюс непонятный хвост.

Пробую вручную выполнить в консоли:

```
"ВА 47-63, 2P 2А (C) EKF".to_s.to_slug.normalize(transliterations: :russian).to_s
=> "va-47-63-2p-2a-c-ekf"
```

На выводе адекватная транслитерация соответствующая ожиданиям.

**Не могу понять почему в консоли транслитерация норм, а через normalize_friendly_id кривая.** Я новичок, поэтому мог что то просто не сделать, хотя делал всё по мануалам.

Таким же образом делал транслитерацю для тегов, она получилась адекватной.

models/tag.rb

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
  belongs_to :product

  def normalize_friendly_id(input)
   input.to_s.to_slug.normalize(transliterations: :russian).to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: Вы проверяли, в этот метод программа вообще заходит? Выдаёт корректный результат?

Comment: где то я сей вопрос уже видел =)

Comment: вы поставьте binding.pry прямо в метод и посмотрите в нём как в консоли в чём проблема